# PHP Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in line 2

Tags: php, user-agent, error-log

I have added a 3 line code at the top of the index page to eliminate the bad request which occurs in imac devices. The code is given below:

```
<?php
if (preg_match ("/CaptiveNetworkSupport/", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])) {
header ("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
exit ();
}
?>
```

But I can see lots of "PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  HTTP_USER_AGENT in " errors in the error_log. How can I remove these logs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe if you test if the index exists before the `preg_match`:

```
    <?php
        if ( isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]) && preg_match ("/CaptiveNetworkSupport/", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]) )
        {
            header ("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
            exit ();
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])` or `array_key_exists( 'HTTP_USER_AGENT', $_SERVER )` to check that the key `HTTP_USER_AGENT` even exists.

When you refer to a key that doesn't exist you get a notice. you can suppress the notices globally in the config but it's a very bad practice.

You can suppress all errors for a single call with the @. eg.: `@$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

(sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 1):

You could make sure it's set first:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]) && preg_match ("/CaptiveNetworkSupport/", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])) {
        header ("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
        exit ();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Header redirects based on user agent detection can get out of control quickly. Quite a few of the sites I've inherited over the years have massive `.htaccess` files that slow down the server connections. For future proofing you might start with an array of searches to check against (sort of like a blacklist). I usually store mine in a database. Here's an example of what works for user_agents and ip_addresses using the same function.

```
<?php
//user agent blacklist array
$uab = array(
'!^$!','!CaptiveNetworkSupport!','!curl!i'
);

//User agent handling array
$uah = array(
'HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request','HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request','HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden',
);

$ipb = array(
'!^1\.2\.3!',
'!^8\.8\.8\.8!',
'!^199\.21!',
'!^0\.0\.0\.0$!',
);

$iph = array(
'Location: /no-bots.php',
'Location: /warning.php',
'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden',
'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden',
);


function blackList($blacklist,$handler,$means){

    foreach($blacklist as $key=>$bl){
        if (preg_match($bl,$means)){
            header($handler[$key]);
            exit();
        }
    }
}

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
  $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];    
} else {
  $user_agent = ''; 
}

blackList($uab,$uah,$user_agent);

//This should always be set!
if(!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){
  $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];    
} else {
    $ip_address = '0.0.0.0';
}

blackList($ipb,$iph,$ip_address);

?>
```

In my custom CMS I have a ban page that allows a backend user a means for determining how the offender gets punished or treated. It's useful for blocking all sorts of things and is best when used in conjunction with iptables.

Comment: I'll just add that user agent-based blocking is often futile anyway. It's trivial for clients to lie in their UA string.